# WHM https with port 8443 throwing warning

Tags: https, port, whm

I have installed Mirth connect and it is running on https://example.com:8443 but it throwing https warning. If I run https://example.com it doesn't show any warning because ssl certificate is instaled. The issue is with the port. Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Mirth Connect generates a new self-signed certificate on first startup. You can replace this with your own cert, it's the "mirthconnect" alias in the keystore.jks file. Follow the **Changing The Server Certificate** section in the user guide.